# MYSQL Join on meta key value?

Tags: mysql

I have very basic mysql knowledge (able to update and join tables) and am using phpMYAdmin but I am trying something just beyond my level now. I have looked at many other questions and answers but cannot find a solution for me. I am sure there is a very simple answer. This is what I am trying to do...

```
usermeta t1 looks like this:
user_id |  meta_key  | meta_value|
---------------------------------------
 1      |   mk1      |  value1  |
 2      |   mk2      |  value2  |
 3      |   desc     |  name    |
 4      |   mk4      |  value4  |
 5      |   desc     |  name    |
 6      |   mk6      |  value6  |
 7      |   mk7      |  value7  |
 8      |   desc     |  name    |
 9      |   mk9      |  value9  |
 10     |   desc     |  name    |

 userdata t2 looks like this:
 user_id  |   desc   |  
 ---------------------
 1        |   bob    |
 2        |   joe    |
 3        |   nancy  |
 4        |   jane   |
 5        |   lee    |
 6        |   jeff   |
 7        |   jill   |
 8        |   scott  |
 9        |   len    |
 10       |   carey  |
```

I want to update the t1 meta_value column in all the cells wtih the value "name", where the meta_key is "desc", with the data from t2.desc column, and joined where t1.user_id = t2.user_id, but I don't know how to do this! Does anyone have some mysql suggestions?

Comment: Are these both custom tables?

Comment: t1 is acting as the default wp_usermeta table while t2 is a table I created just to get the data in the database for the join and will dump after I find the solution.

Comment: Is this the result of a query? Or is this the database description? Post the description please.

Comment: The above is a description of what I am trying to do.

Comment: @user2591811  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can update just joining both table on comparing same userid. like:

```
update t1 join
       t2
       on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    set t1.meta_value = t2.desc;
```